# String Tokenizer Not Registering String on Second Line as a Token When Reading File Despite Using .nextToken()

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am trying to read a file. The file in question has two strings, one on its own line, like this:

COMETQ
HVNGAT

I am trying to assign each string to its own String variable. However, when I run my code (below), I get a NoSuchElementException for the second .nextToken().

```
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ride.out")));

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());

    String comet = st.nextToken();
    String group = st.nextToken();
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong? Thank you!

Note: this is a USACO training page problem. I am just trying to seek help to debug the file reading, not solve the problem.

Comment: Why not use `Scanner`?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart I would, but the USACO training page strongly recommends using BufferedReader/StringTokenizer because it's a lot faster, so I'm trying to figure out how to do this using this method.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about that (I did USACO problems for a while)

Comment: If i'm not wrong `f.readLine()` will read only first line right?

Comment: Just call `f.readLine()` twice to read the two lines into two strings. No need for `StringTokenizer` here. BTW the docs say “`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.”

Answer (score 0):

You only gave it one line:

```java
new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
```

You'll have to read all the lines from the file first, then pass the resulting string to the constructor.

Note: in this case, you don't even have to use the `StringTokenizer`. Just use the `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 0):

**StringTokenizer should be used when text contains delimiters and you want to split. You can also use split() method also.**

Syntax :

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text, delimiter);
```

For example :

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer("abc, def", ",");
```

But in your file, there is no such delimiter present in the string. So, `StringTokenizer` is of no use here.

I have tested with this :

```
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("F:/test.txt")));
            String line;
            String extracted = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);  
                while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                    extracted = extracted + stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString() +",";
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            String[] splits = extracted.split(",");
            String comet = splits[0];
            String group = splits[1];
            System.out.println(comet + " " + group);
```

Output :

```
COMETQ HVNGAT
```

Hope this helps you :)